# Какова разница между процессами и потоками в python?

Tags: python, peewee

На данный момент я имею много-поточное приложение написанное на py3.7,которое работает с апи мессенджера. Обработкой каждого сообщения занимается отдельный поток. В своём приложении я использую sqlite3, для работы с базой данных, и не так давно я наткнулся на лок базы данных, предположительно из-за того, что каждый созданный поток так или иначе взаимодействовал с базой данных, и в какой-то момент потоки пересеклись, создавая запись в БД в одно и то же время.
Команда fuser показала, что одну и ту же базу данных использовало сразу несколько потоков одновременно даже после остановки главного приложения.
Отсюда вопрос - какова принципиальная разница между потоками и процессами в python, и закрываются ли процессы/потоки автоматически, после завершения задачи?
Так же, если я заменю все свои процессы на потоки - остаётся ли вероятность повторного лока базы данных?
Для работы с БД использую PeeWee ORM'ку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потоки это те же самые потоки, что и в других языках, но они синхронизируюится через GIL. Одновременно выполняется только один поток. Переменные у потоков общие.

Процессы выполняются раздельно и у каждого свой отдельный GIL. Процессы выполняются одновременно. Переменные не помещенные в общую память у каждого процесса свои. Процессы могут завершаться вместе с главным, а могут не завершиться.

Для вычислений с нагрузкой на CPU лучше использовать процессы. Для ожидания ввода-вывода, работе с файлами и сетью подойдут и потоки.

На потоках у вас будет одно подключение к базе данных.

Comment: А как понять - могут завершаться, а могут не завершиться? Т.е. это рандомно всё, или можно как-то проконтролировать и принудительно завершить процесс после выполнения задачи? Если можно - то как?

Comment: Ну смотря чем они там занимались - если процесс завис, то может не завершиться.  Можно настроить чтоб чтоб главный пересылал им сигнал на завершение, можно их отсоединить от контроля.